# How can I make this jQuery plugin chainable after all image load events have completed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

**[UPDATE] Solution I decided on:**

Decided that passing in a callback to the plugin will take care of firing an event once all images have completed loading. Chaining is also still possible.  [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jXjT7/37/)

---

I am building a chainable jQuery plugin that can load images dynamically.

(View the following code as a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jXjT7/26/))

**Html:**

```
<img data-img-src="http://www.lubasf.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/gnome.jpg" style="display: none" />

<img data-img-src="http://buffered.io/uploads/2008/10/gnome.jpg" style="display: none" />
```

Instead of adding in a `src` attribute, I give these images a `data-img-src` attribute. My plugin uses the value of that to fill the `src`.  Also, these images are hidden to begin with.

**jQuery plugin:**

```
(function(jQuery) {
jQuery.fn.loadImages = function() { 
    var numToLoad = jQuery(this).length;
    var numLoaded = 0;
    jQuery(this).each(function() { 
        if(jQuery(this).attr('src') == undefined) {
            return jQuery(this).load(function() {
                numLoaded++;
                if(numToLoad == numLoaded)
                    return this; // attempt at making this plugin 
                                 // chainable, after all .load()
                                 // events have completed.
            }).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('data-img-src'));
        } else {
            numLoaded++;
            if(numToLoad == numLoaded)
                return this; // attempt at making this plugin 
                             // chainable, after all .load()
                             // events have completed.
        }
    });
    // this works if uncommented, but returns before all .load() events have completed
    //return this;
};
})(jQuery);


// I want to chain a .fadeIn() after all images have completed loading
$('img[data-img-src]').loadImages().fadeIn();
```

Is there a way to make this plugin chainable, and have my `fadeIn()` happen after all images have loaded?

Comment: using fadeIn() instead of show() appears to give the desired behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/ey8UL/4/ what am I missing?

Comment: Visually it looks right, but I am trying to build a plugin that can be used to preload images. I am going to have a lot of images loading up, and I want this to reach the show() or fadeIn() only once all images have finished loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get the load() call to perform synchronously is to set it beforehand with,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});
```

That will halt the code execution until the load has completed, then you can return normally.

http://jsfiddle.net/jXjT7/31/

Comment: I am having trouble applying this to my plugin. Do you think it would work?

Comment: this still shows one image, loads the next, then shows the second image.  I am trying to show them only once the two images have loaded.

Comment: @BumbleB2na OOOOOH. I missed that part. That is exactly what my code does, remove the hidden from the images and you will see they are loaded before either show is called.

Comment: yea.. i'm starting to think this is the only way without feeding a callback function to the plugin

Comment: man.. i am confusing myself with the alerts in my show() function. I'm going to try this with a couple of large image files but I think you're right.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm going with this solution where I pass in a callback to the plugin, as well as allow it to be chainable.  The alerts are so deceiving, but it now works how I wanted it to.  http://jsfiddle.net/jXjT7/37/

Answer (score 2):

Like RedWolves stated above, you should use:

```
return this.each(function() { //.....
```

so that your code is chainable.

You mentioned that you want to execute this when everything has loaded. To do that, you should wrap your code in jQuery's $() function, which takes an inline, anonymous function which will execute when the DOM has loaded.

So in your case, it would be:

```
jQuery(function($){    // jQuery is the same as $, and it passes itself to the function
    $('img[data-img-src]').loadImages().fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: I know to wrap it in dom ready. I should have adjusted that in my code sample. I am playing around with RedWolves' suggestion and still have not got it working the way I want.

Comment: Does this do something similar to what you want?[jsFiddle example, tweaked](http://jsfiddle.net/jXjT7/34/)

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to wrap this in the jQuery function.  this already points to the jQuery object.
2. Return this will return the jQuery object to be chainable  so on this line

jQuery(this).each(function() {

replace it with this

return this.each(function() {

That'll make your plugin chainable See the [Authoring guide for more help](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Maintaining_Chainability)

Comment: I tried `return this.each(function() {` but it returns each before they have all finished loading. See what I mean?  http://jsfiddle.net/jXjT7/29/   I am trying to make this work sort of like a jQuery effect plugin, so that the chained `.show()` will only fire once everything has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is correct that there is no way to delay the call to chained functions, like 'fadeIn' in your example, except if loading with synchronous ajax request. Not too applicable for image tags loading and such though...

But he is forgetting one interesting detail... animation methods like fadeIn don't perform their animations immediately when called, but use an animation queue. So in your case, you really do not mind if fadeIn gets called immediately, you just want the animation queue to be paused until the images have loaded.

You can do that for example by doing a .delay(1000000000) when your plugin is called, and then .stop() later when the images have loaded.

A more politically correct way to do the same thing is instead of .delay() to .queue() a function that stores its first parameter, and instead of .stop() call that stored parameter when the images have loaded.

EDIT: your fixed fiddle jsfiddle.net/jXjT7/42/